# Adding scripts to gameobjects at runtime with PUN

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I have a coop game that I'd like to extend to online multiplayer. My game has a series of minigames, sort of like mario party but in a single level. My current code adds and removes scripts from the player objects at runtime depending on the current minigame. For example, when the Tag game loads, it automatically adds the TagPlayerScript to each player, and then removes it once the game ends.

The way I manage this is with a single GameEngine class that iterates through each player in a list.

With Photon, I can't figure out how to make this functionality work. I can instantiate a player prefab for each player, but if I add a script during runtime it only does so on one player's version of the game. How can I make it update on every player's game?

Comment: You can do a local check for each player. if mini-game N is currently enabled, then the each player must enable script X on self

Comment: Yeah instead of iterating through each player you go the other way round and each player checks the current state/game/etc and reacts accordingly